# Как копировать ссылку в буфер по нажатию?

Tags: android

У меня есть кнопка, по нажатию которой пользователь делиться ссылкой в приложениях и т.д
Вот ее код:

```
    private void shareURL() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            getResources().getString(R.string.web_share_end)
                    + browser.getUrl());
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources()
            .getString(R.string.share)));
}
```

Как сделать так, что бы ссылка просто копировалась в буфер обмена?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String url = "http://google.com";
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText(label, url);
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```